# Definir comportamento da tecla TAB - javaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Eu não manjo nada de JavaScript e preciso de uma mãozinha da comunidade.
Na verdade nem sei se o que eu vou pedir é possível, mas é o seguinte:
Conforme imagem a seguir, eu preciso de uma função que, supondo que o cursor esteja no campo identificado com o número 1, ao teclar sucessivamente o TAB, ao atingir o botão identificado com o número 8, no próximo TAB, retorne para o campo de número 1, ao invés de continuar para os demais campos e botões da página  (identificado por número 9 em diante):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aí vai o código do html gerado via php com base em dados de banco próprio, então as "id" de alguns inputs podem não parecer ter lógica, mas enfim, também é só pra exemplo (talvez a formatação css não pegue nesse código, mas não é importante):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Exemplo</title>
  <link href="./PREGÃO WEB - MUNICÍPIO DE GUARAPUAVA - Pregão20_2020_files/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="icon" href="http://info.guarapuava.pr.gov.br/pregao/img/index.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://info.guarapuava.pr.gov.br/pregao/img/index.ico" type="image/x-icon">

</head>

<body class="container">
  <script src="./PREGÃO WEB - MUNICÍPIO DE GUARAPUAVA - Pregão20_2020_files/jquery.min.js.download"></script>
  <script src="./PREGÃO WEB - MUNICÍPIO DE GUARAPUAVA - Pregão20_2020_files/bootstrap.min.js.download"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function declinaProposta(indice) {

      document.getElementById("tdOferta" + indice).className = "text-center danger";

      //alert("declina");
    }
  </script>

  <div>
    <legend class="text-uppercase"><strong>Página exemplo</strong><br>AQUISIÇÃO DE MATERIAIS ESPORTIVOS, COM RECURSOS ORIUNDOS DA LEI N.º 2933/2019. SECRETARIA MUNICIPAL DE ESPORTES E RECREAçãO</legend>
    <form action="http://info.guarapuava.pr.gov.br/pregao/index.php" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="form" value="c-4">
      <legend>Disputa por Lances</legend>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-lg-9">
            <select name="nrLoteItem" class="form-control">
              <optgroup label="Não Disputados"></optgroup>
              <optgroup label="Disputados">
                <option value="1.1" selected="selected">Lote 1 - Item 1 - TATAME, 1X1, 40MM EM E.V.A. MONOCOLOR, 1ª LINHA, DUPLA FACE</option>
                <option value="2.1">Lote 2 - Item 1 - DARDOS DE BAMBU PARA ATLETISMO - - DARDO DE BAMBU PARA ATL</option>
                <option value="3.1">Lote 3 - Item 1 - BOLA DE HANDEBOL - - BOLA DE HANDEBOL H1 – PRODUZIDA EM </option>
                <option value="4.1">Lote 4 - Item 1 - BOLA DE HANDEBOL FEMININO H2L, CONFECCIONADA EM PU, TAMANHO </option>
                <option value="5.1">Lote 5 - Item 1 - BOLA DE HANDEBOL SUÉCIA H3L MASCULINA, CONFECCIONADA EM PU,</option>
                <option value="6.1">Lote 6 - Item 1 - BOLA DE VOLEIBOL OFICIAL - - BOLA VÔLEI 8.0 PRO IX DESENV</option>
              </optgroup>
              <optgroup label="Frustrados"></optgroup>
              <optgroup label="Desertos"></optgroup>
              <optgroup label="Cancelados"></optgroup>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3">
            <button type="submit" name="Operacao" value="1" class="form-control btn btn-primary">Carregar Lote para Disputa</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div><br>
  <div>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="text-center">Licitante</th>
          <th class="text-center">MPE</th>
          <th class="text-center">Âmbito</th>
          <th class="text-center">%</th>
          <th class="text-center">Proposta</th>
          <th colspan="2" class="text-center">Oferta</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <form action="http://info.guarapuava.pr.gov.br/pregao/index.php" method="post"></form>
        <input type="hidden" name="form" value="c-4">
        <input type="hidden" name="nrLote" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="nrItem" value="1">
        <tr class="dangero">
          <td><input type="hidden" name="Lance[0][nrDocumentoLicitante]" value="33361168000181">
            C R ROSOLEN &amp; CIA LTDA</td>
          <td width="30px" class="text-center">Sim</td>
          <td width="30px" class="text-center">Fora</td>
          <td width="30px" class="text-center">72,62</td>
          <td width="30px" class="text-center"><input type="hidden" name="Lance[0][vlProposta]" value="145.00">
            145,00</td>
          <td width="30px" id="tdOferta0" name="tdOferta0" class="text-center"><input type="number" name="Lance[0][vlOferta]" style="width:80px;" step="0.01"></td>
          <td width="30px" class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default form-control" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; height: 26px;" onclick="declinaProposta(0)">Declinar</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="hidden" name="Lance[1][nrDocumentoLicitante]" value="30926482000176">
            SERGIO LUIZ DA CRUZ ARTIGOS ESPORTIVOS</td>
          <td width="30px" class="text-center">Sim</td>
          <td width="30px" class="text-center">Local</td>
          <td width="30px" class="text-center">64,83</td>
          <td width="30px" class="text-center"><input type="hidden" name="Lance[1][vlProposta]" value="138.46">
            138,46</td>
          <td width="30px" id="tdOferta1" name="tdOferta1" class="text-center"><input type="number" name="Lance[1][vlOferta]" style="width:80px;" step="0.01"></td>
          <td width="30px" class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default form-control" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; height: 26px;" onclick="declinaProposta(1)">Declinar</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="hidden" name="Lance[2][nrDocumentoLicitante]" value="04611754000139">
            SUPERBALL SPORTS MATERIAL ESPORTIVO LTDA</td>
          <td width="30px" class="text-center">Sim</td>
          <td width="30px" class="text-center">Fora</td>
          <td width="30px" class="text-center">7,14</td>
          <td width="30px" class="text-center"><input type="hidden" name="Lance[2][vlProposta]" value="90.00">
            90,00</td>
          <td width="30px" id="tdOferta2" name="tdOferta2" class="text-center"><input type="number" name="Lance[2][vlOferta]" style="width:80px;" step="0.01"></td>
          <td width="30px" class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default form-control" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; height: 26px;" onclick="declinaProposta(2)">Declinar</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="hidden" name="Lance[3][nrDocumentoLicitante]" value="28248986000132">
            TIAGO DANIEL VEDAN</td>
          <td width="30px" class="text-center">Sim</td>
          <td width="30px" class="text-center">Fora</td>
          <td width="30px" class="text-center">0,00</td>
          <td width="30px" class="text-center"><input type="hidden" name="Lance[3][vlProposta]" value="84.00">
            84,00</td>
          <td width="30px" id="tdOferta3" name="tdOferta3" class="text-center"><input type="number" name="Lance[3][vlOferta]" style="width:80px;" step="0.01"></td>
          <td width="30px" class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default form-control" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; height: 26px;" onclick="declinaProposta(3)">Declinar</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="text-center"><button type="submit" name="Operacao" value="7" class="btn btn-default">Reiniciar Lances</button></td>
          <td colspan="6" class="text-right"><button type="submit" name="Operacao" value="2" class="btn btn-success">Gravar Lances</button></td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>

    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o atributo [`tabindex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex), que define a sequência de foco em uma página. Veja um exemplo:

```css
input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input tabindex="1" />
<input tabindex="3" />
<input tabindex="5" />
<input tabindex="7" />
<input tabindex="8" />
<input tabindex="6" />
<input tabindex="4" />
<input tabindex="2" />
```

Comment: A princípio havia aceito como a solução perfeita. porém, quando atinge cursor atinge o ultimo input ele percorre todo o restante da página, não retornando para o primeiro, como solicitado. Mas foi útil pq em conversa com um amigo, ele falou, que ao atingir o ultimo,dá pra usar o onblur para selecionar o próximo campo pelo tabindex=1 atraves de javascript